# deploy .net 6 mvc project to app engine flex evn

Tags: asp.net-core, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, asp.net-core-mvc

ı wanna deploy a project to google cloud app engine but encountered a problem.

First, I created a folder in app engine ssh and created a net6 project in this folder, then "dotnet restore" this project.
I restored it with code. Then I published it with the code "dotnet publish -c Release". Then I added the Dockerfile and app.yaml files that I showed into the publish file. Also, my launchSettings.json file is as follows.
Although I do all these configurations and run the "gcloud app deploy" code under the publish folder, I get the log image as below and after saying "gcloud app browse" I get the "502 Bad Gateway" nginx error on the page I go to. What is the reason of this.

Logs :

[image]

Dockerfile :

```
ADD / /app
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://localhost:8080
WORKDIR /app
ENTRYPOINT [ "dotnet", "giveawayproject.dll"]
```

app.yaml :

```
runtime: custom
env: flex

# This sample incurs costs to run on the App Engine flexible environment. 
# The settings below are to reduce costs during testing and are not appropriate
# for production use. For more information, see:
# https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/dotnet/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml
manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
resources:
  cpu: 2
  memory_gb: 6
  disk_size_gb: 30

env_variables:
  # The __ in My__Greeting will be translated to a : by ASP.NET.
  My__Greeting: Hello AppEngine!
```

launchSettings.json :

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:8080",
      "sslPort": 44302
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "Wizz.Giveaway.Mvc": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:8080",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you already checked this [troubleshooting guide](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/troubleshoot-response-errors#bad_gateway)?

Comment: thanks. I fixed  as I explained in the bottom post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I modified the dockerfile. The application worked. As far as I understand, the port was not working because I did not export it.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0
ADD / /app
EXPOSE 8080
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://*:8080
WORKDIR /app
ENTRYPOINT [ "dotnet", "giveawayproject.dll"]
```